# Visual Studio 2012 Unit Test client and service debug

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Dumb question but for some reason I just can't seem to figure out how to debug a unit test, hit a breakpoint on the client and step into a web service. In VS 2010 I just set my solution to be a Multiple Startup Projeects and set the debug to the client UI test and also the web service. When my breakpoint hit in the UI test I could step into the web service. In VS 2012, I don't see a way to do that. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can hit the breakpoint in your unit test? It just steps over your webservice call? Have you already tried setting a breakpoint in your webservice?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't hit that breakpoint. I think it's because the debugger isn't attached to that project however I don't know how to get visual studio to attach to that process.

Comment: Test menu Test - Debug All Tests in solution

Answer (score 4):

1. Start the website without debugging (if it's not already running).
2. Put a breakpoint in your unit test.
3. Start your unit test.
4. When the breakpoint is hit, use **Debug > Attach to Process** to attach to **iisexpress.exe**.

The [official instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243172.aspx) are wrong. They say to attach the debugger first, but if you do that, the commands to start your unit test are disabled.

Always having to manually attach can be a pain. There doesn't seem to be a way to do it quickly [from the Command Window](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6443298/145173). If I had to do a lot of debug cycles, I'd temporarily copy the test code into the web application somewhere that would get run at startup.

Comment: For those not using iisexpress but the builtin development server the process is named Webdev.webserver.exe

Answer (score 0):

Run two instances of Visual Studio. In one instance, debug the website. In the other, run the unit tests.

To keep the unit-test instance from trying to start the website, select the website project, click **View > Properties Window**, and ensure **Always Start When Debugging** is **False**.